# Regular expression to get all matches in string ends with

Tags: regex

Please help me to develop a regular expression which will return all matches in a string if its end with (&any character)
Eg. String a="abcd(&w)", then matches should have value (&w)
If a="abcd(&w), xhz(&d), then there should be two matches
Note: in place of comma (,) above it can be any delimiter list [','':',';'.........]

If abcd(&w)pqrsr, xhz(&d). Then matches should be only (&d) and not (&w) since it is not in end before delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
\(&.\)(?=[,:;]|$)
```

This will match a literal `(&` followed by any character, followed by a literal `)`. It also requires that the next character be one of `,`, `:`, or `;` or that the match is followed by the end of the string.

Comment: (s)he doesn't want to have the last delimiter in the match, so you should add a group to exclude it (`(\(&.\))(?=[,:;]|$)`)

Comment: @GiulioFranco The delimiter (`[,:;]`) will not be part of the match since it's in a lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Just build the regular expressions. For example, `abcd(&w)` would be `.*[w]$`, here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/eA7oZ7) to prove it. If you needed more than one character, like this `abcd(&w), xhz(&d)`, then the Regex would be `.*[wd]$`.

However, you're going to have to parse those strings you get as input to build the Regex. For example, you might do something like:

```
var regex = "abcd(&w)".Replace("(&", "[").Replace(")", "]");
```

or for two you might do something like this:

```
var input = "abcd(&w), xhz(&d)";
var exps = input.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var startChars = new List<string>();
var endChars = new List<string>();

foreach (var ex in exps)
{
    if (ex.Substring(ex.Length - 3, 1) == "&")
    {
        startChars.Add(ex.Substring(0, ex.IndexOf("(")));
        endChars.Add(ex.Substring(ex.IndexOf("&") + 1, 1));
    }
}

var regex = string.Format("{0}[{1}]$",
    string.Join("|", startChars.ToArray()),
    string.Join("", endChars.ToArray()));
```

That would build a Regex like this `abcd|xhz[wd]$`.